# trying to make symbolic link but have spaces in folder name

Tags: windows, command-line, sync, symbolic-link

I'm trying to make a symbolic link via the windows command prompt. I am using a drop box-like service called Copy. it creates a new folder which it syncs to the web and other computers that it's installed on. I want to sync my pictures folder to it without creating duplicates on the hard drive.

This is the command I'm entering, but I keep getting an error message, and i think it has to do with the space in my folder name. Please let me know if that's the problem and what i can to do fix it. thank you in advance

> C:\mklink /D C:\Users\Drew\Copy myemailaddress@gmail.com\Pictures C:\Users\Drew\Pictures

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this for your spaces:

```
%\
```

---

Or setting the path in double quotes:

```
C:\mklink /D C:\Users\Drew\Copy myemailaddress@gmail.com\Pictures "C:\Users\Drew\Pictures"
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!

Do I need to mark this thread as resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you need to link a name containing spaces to a target containing spaces, you need to enclose both of them in quotes:

```
C:> mklink /D "My Documents" "C:\OneDrive - My User\Documents"
```